# lock on Clear Case vob database and prevents all write operations

Tags: clearcase

I am getting an error while checking out the file.

> Error is: lock on VOB database "\EPAS prevents all write operations.

I tried to unlock the VOB but no luck.

> Cleartool: Error: Object is not locked.
>
> Cleartool: Error: Unable to unlock versioned object base "\EPAS_NF".

I even try to run the Protect VOB. still, the VOB is not working.
Please let me know how to unlock the VOB.

Comment: When I try to unlock the VOB got the below error:

Comment: db_event_create_V3: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = [WINSOCK] Connection reset by peer. cleartool: Error: Trouble communicating with VOB database: "\EPAS_NF". Check database log on VOB host "ner02108".
db_abort_trans_V3: RPC: Unable to send; erro = [WINSOCK] Connection reset by peer. Cleartool: Error: INTERNAL ERROR detected and logged with the NT Event Service. See the Event Viewer for the error message.
Cleartool: Error: Trouble communicating with VOB database: "\EPAS_NF".
Check database log on VOB host "ner02108".
Cleartool: Error: Unable to lock versioned object base

Comment: I have tried with protectvob command and got this error.

Comment: cleartool: Warning: Versioned object base owner is already "FORDEU1\EUCCADM".
cleartool: Warning: Versioned object base group is already "FORDEU1\7136-EUDAUSER".
Pool "sdft" appears to be protected correctly.
Pool "ddft" appears to be protected correctly.
Pool "cdft" appears to be protected correctly.
cleartool: Error: Lock on VOB database "\EPAS_NF" prevents all write operations.
cleartool: Error: Trouble protecting versioned object base "\\ner91a0030\proj\clearcase_prod\VOBSTORE\GVDAS\EPAS_NF2.vbs".

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on your:

- ClearCase version (an [old one would have dbcheck](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21203130) for instance)
  (a ClearCase 8 had [issue on Vobs idle for too long](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI81268))
- ClearCase usage (a [multiSite one can exhibit VOB communication issue](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21289049))
  (a [multiSite migrated Vob can have lock issue](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21238708))

Looking at the Windows Event viewer can help pinpoint the issue (a network communication of some sorts)

Answer (score 0):

I have a vague recollection of seeing something like this come across as a tech support case. Ah, there it is... There were a number of other errors in your VOB server logs as I recall, including the \EPAS_NF or \EPAS VOB not being registered.

I am guessing that \EPAS_NF is an admin VOB to \EPAS, or vice versa. If you are checking out on a VOB where a given global brtype has never been instantiated, and the Admin VOB is locked, you will get an error stating that the admin VOB is locked.

This being said, I would make sure that the VOBs in question are currently fully and correctly registered and tagged, and that both databases are at least basically intact using dbcheck.

If you are getting an error message stating that the VOB is not consistently locked, it stands to reason that there is at least SOME database corruption, that should appear in a dbcheck or in a reformatvob.

The support case does not mention a timeline for the issue. And that may be key to knowing how you got into this mess... And in the case of corrupt databases, having some idea as to the cause would assist in knowing how practical database recovery will be.

Comment: cleartool: Warning: Versioned object base owner is already "FORDEU1\EUCCADM".
cleartool: Warning: Versioned object base group is already "FORDEU1\7136-EUDAUSER".
Pool "sdft" appears to be protected correctly.
Pool "ddft" appears to be protected correctly.
Pool "cdft" appears to be protected correctly.
cleartool: Error: Lock on VOB database "\EPAS_NF" prevents all write operations.
cleartool: Error: Trouble protecting versioned object base "\\ner91a0030\proj\clearcase_prod\VOBSTORE\GVDAS\EPAS_NF2.vbs".

Comment: As I mentioned, if you get told the VOB is locked, yet unlock tells you it's not, there is a database problem that needs to be resolved.